# Will AWS autoscaling groups end Druid processes that are still running tasks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, druid

I want to run Druid on EKS but was concerned about using EC2 autoscaling groups to scale my middle managers. If every middle manager is running an ingestion task but AWS decides to scale down, will a middle manager be terminated or will there be termination protection in place? If so, what other alternatives to scaling do people suggest?

Answer (score 0):

A signal will be sent to your containers to give them an opportunity to shutdown gracefully. This is part of [lifecycle management](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#hook-handler-execution).

By default, the orchestrator will wait 30 seconds before forcefully stopping the container. You can adjust this by setting `terminationGracePeriodSeconds`. You can also add hooks like `PostStart` or `PreStop` to do any extra operations to ensure consistency in your system.

See also: [EC2 Autoscaling lifecycle hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html)